# How to stop docker-compose from doing unwanted replication

Tags: docker, docker-compose, replication

I've got a very simple single-host docker compose setup:

```
version: "3"

services:
  bukofka:
    image: picoglavar
    restart: always
    environment:
    - PORT=8000
    - MODEL=/models/large
    volumes:
    - glavar:/models

  chlenix:
    image: picoglavar
    restart: always
    environment:
    - PORT=8000
    - MODEL=/models/small
    volumes:
    - glavar:/models

# ... other containers ...
```

As you can see, it's only two services based off a single image, so nothing special really. When I open up `docker ps` I can see these two services churning. And there I open htop and see that each python application is run at least **four** times; this is very surprising because I haven't setup any in-container kind of replication, and I'm not running this in any kind of swarm mode.

Why does this happen?

[image: htop]

Comment: where are you running htop?

Comment: Note that the lines in green are threads, not processes: https://superuser.com/a/1496571/173193

Comment: @NickODell I'm an idiot... thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm a complete idiot. And colour blind too, apparently.

> Note that the lines in green are threads, not processes: https://superuser.com/a/1496571/173193

per @nick-odell